# Format Trello card title

Tags: trello-cards

Can the Trello card title be formatted into three lines of text? I basically want to see more data on the cards when viewed on the board.

Answer (score 4):

There are no plans to add such a feature. You could use the card description for more detail.

Comment: Thank you for quick response. Does the card description show on card cover when viewed on board?

Comment: No, since it's meant to be long and detailed. If we showed it, you wouldn't have any more space for cards.

Comment: @BobbyGrace But, IMHO, the tooltip that now pops up when you hover the cursor over the pencil icon could show the description instead of showing the message "This card has a description". BTW, you guys have put together a smart tool, I should say; I am a new trello user, I have just been using it these days... :)